# Can't get data from a static array in HelperAdmin

Tags: oop, yii, static-methods, web-frameworks, static-variables

I have a file/class::method (HelperAdmin.php/HelperAdmin::menuItem()) which extracts data from DB to generate main menu and submenu.
I have to get this data after the menu being generated but I don't want to call this method twice.
So I have created a static array in HelperAdmin class. It looks like this:

```
class HelperAdmin {
        static $arrMenuItems;
                ...
                public static function menuItem() {
                      ....get $items....
                     self::$arrMenuItems = $items;
                     return $items;
                }
        ....
}
```

But here is a problem. If I call the METHOD again:

```
$items=HelperAdmin::menuItem();
```

...I can get data. 
In other hand if I try to get data through a static array:

```
$items=HelperAdmin::$arrMenuItems;
```

...it just returns null.

### I hope to see some ideas. After all, if your opinion is that using static variable here (from Yii architecture view) is not the best solution, I'd like to get your advice!

**@bool.dev**:
OK, imagine the following scheme:
1. We have the main file

```
/modules/admin/views/layouts/admin.php
```

which is in essence our backend template.
2. We have the helper here:

```
/modules/admin/components/HelperAdmin.php
```

which contains: 
  * a class HelperAdmin, 
  * menuItem() method and 
  * a class static array $arrMenuItems. 
A content of this ARRAY returned by calling HelperAdmin::menuItem().
We want get data from the HelperAdmin class twice:
  1. While generating a menu in **admin.php**;
  2. As part of content which we get with variable **$content** putting it at this file.
$content in turn is generated in another file:

```
/modules/admin/views/generator/index.php
```

So as you can see, our page compounds itself from the template file /modules/admin/views/layouts/admin.php and data ($content) getting from /modules/admin/views/generator/index.php.
First I get data for menu:

```
HelperAdmin::menuItem();
$items=HelperAdmin::$arrMenuItems;
$this->widget(....
        'items'=>$items,
        ...),
    ));
```

That's OK. Notice that after this a static array $arrMenuItems **already is generated in HelperAdmin**.
Next I'm trying to get the same data ($arrMenuItems generated earlier) in file /modules/admin/views/generator/index.php to place it as **$content**:

```
$items=HelperAdmin::$arrMenuItems
```

And here I can't get it as described above. 
Well, I hope it made a situation more clear (?).

Comment: this can be done in a different way, can you show how you are initializing the `$arrMenuItems`? and how are you using it in the menu? maybe then i can suggest something

Comment: I added the information. Look at the second part of the question pls.